# How to put a custom view into an NSImageWell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have made what I thought was a perfect start to an image editor. It draws a square wherever you click. My problem is that when you click in a different place, or drag the mouse, it just moves the square (instead of drawing another one). How can I draw in a custom view without "dragging" it's current contents everywhere?

Here is my code:

Header (.h)

```
NSBezierPath *thePath;
NSColor *theColor;
NSTimer *updateTimer;
NSPoint *mousePoint;
int testInt = 1;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

@interface test : NSView {
    IBOutlet NSView *myView;
    IBOutlet NSButton *button;

}

@property (readwrite) NSPoint mousePoint;

@end
```

.m file (whatever it is called)

```
@implementation test

@synthesize mousePoint;

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)someEvent {         
    mousePoint = [someEvent locationInWindow];
    NSLog(@"Location: x= %f, y = %f", (float)mousePoint.x, (float)mousePoint.y);
    x = mousePoint.x;
    y = mousePoint.y;
    [button setHidden:TRUE];
    [button setHidden:FALSE];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

} 

- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)someEvent {
    mousePoint = [someEvent locationInWindow];
    NSLog(@"Location: x= %f, y = %f", (float)mousePoint.x, (float)mousePoint.y);
    x = mousePoint.x;
    y = mousePoint.y;
    [button setHidden:TRUE];
    [button setHidden:FALSE];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}

- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)rect; {
    thePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(x, y, 10, 10)];
    theColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    [theColor set];
    [thePath fill];

}

@end
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

It moves your current rectangle around, because that's the only rectangle there is. If you want to draw multiple rectangles and have them persist, you need to store the `NSBezierPath` objects that represent the rectangles somewhere (I would suggest an `NSArray`) and then iterate through the array and draw each one.

Looking at your current code, you should implement `mouseUp:` and store an `NSBezierPath` object with your x and y coordinates in an `NSArray`. Then in `drawRect:` just loop through the array of `NSBezierPath` objects and draw each one.